# Nested breakable frames

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox

I am trying to solve problem with nested frame environments which must be both breakable. It is not important to use `tcolorbox` if there is some better alternative.

Is it possible to display it correctly? Imagine the situation below. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced]
        \lipsum[1-6]

        \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced]
            \lipsum[1-6]
        \end{tcolorbox}

    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `tcolorbox` manual clearly states: Nesting of breakable box inside a breakable box is not possible! The inner `breakable` specification`  will be  ignored. Perhaps you should state what you really want to achieve

Answer (score 4):

The best without further information you can achieve is to use `enforce breakable`, but as the manual of `tcolorbox` states:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced]
        \lipsum[1-6]

        \begin{tcolorbox}[enforce breakable, enhanced]
            \lipsum[1-6]
        \end{tcolorbox}

    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

The screen shot shows the broken outer `tcolorbox` which ends in the middle of nowhere, the remaining contents appear on the 3rd and 4th pages. (not shown here)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I know about this. That's why I am asking if there is any other breakable environment which will work in tcolorbox.

Comment: @sssss: I know of none